# On certain umbilic surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lorentzian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a three dimensional Lorentzian manifold with signature $(-,+,+)$ and let $p\in M$ and let $U$ be a small neighborhood of $p$. Suppose there is a smooth timelike surface $S$ containing $p$ such that $S\cap U$ is umbilic and such that given any $q \in S\cap U$ and any non zero null vector $N \in T_qS$, the null geodesic emanating from $q$ in the direction of $N$ lies on $S\cap U$.

My question is as follows: We know that there is a conformal factor $c>0$ such that for the conformally scaled metric $\hat{g}=cg$, the second fundamental form of $S\cap U$ vanishes identically. Now writing $\hat{R}$ for the conformally scaled curvature tensor on $(M,\hat{g})$, and writing $\nu$ for the normal unit vector field to the surface $S$, is it true that $\hat{R}(N,\nu,N,\nu)=0$ for all $q \in S\cap U$ and all null vectors $N\in T_qS$?